# Mathematical morphology - Erosion. Am I understanding it wrong?

Tags: c#

I have to do that filter, I've found nice article about that (http://www.codersource.net/csharp_image_processing_erosion.aspx), but why the value 11 ([on this picture](http://www.codersource.net/images/ImageProcessing_Csharp_Errosion_erosion_gray_image.GIF)) isn't instead value 16 and 19 (in the second row). This value is the minimum yet.

Comment: Which value 11? There are several 11s on this picture

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Erosion in a gray-scale image takes the minimum of the values around the pixel according to the structuring element.
If you put the cross shaped structuring element on the element in the second row with initial value 19, you'll realize that its neighborhood is the cells with values 23(up), 42(left), 255(right), 11(down) and 19(the cell it self). Out of these, 11 is the minimum value so the value after erosion is 11.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a mapping function to change the value of each pixel. For a particular pixel, say 56 in the article, you are wondering what the new eroded value should be. So you take that 3x3 binary mask and center it on the 56 pixel. Then you take they minimum value of the neighbor pixels wherever there is a one in the mask. So you take the minimum of 198 (top), 78 (bottom), 32 (left neighbor), 16 (right neighbor), and 56, the center itself. Obviously, the minimum value is 16. So 16 is the new, eroded value for what used to be 56. You just do this for every pixel and you get an eroded image. Cool!

Answer to your added question:

Pretend you have an old picture and a new one. You calculate new values from the old ones only. So the 11 is a new value. You don't use it. You just use old values. So you get 19 from the pixel to the left of 255, and the minimum is 16, the one above the 255

Answer (score 0):

I see one problem with the result: the borders are not eroded. Probably due to laziness (the structuring element would go over 'the edge')

The inner result values seem fine though. Please note that the structuring element only looks at the pixels above/below and left/right of the current pixel. 11 is correct since it's the minimum.